# Python UTF-8 decode error for protobuf SerializeToString() data

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I need to post some protobuf data to an API endpoint. I have to decode it first before making an API call but decode fails when the version int contains more than 1 number. This works:

```py
appinfo = app.InstalledAppInfo()
appinfo.name = str(name)
appinfo.version = 1
data = appinfo.SerializeToString().decode("utf-8")
```

But when I try with a larger number, it fails:

```py
appinfo = app.InstalledAppInfo()
appinfo.name = str(name)
appinfo.version = 1342424242
data = appinfo.SerializeToString().decode("utf-8")
```

This is the exact error that I get:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 25: invalid start byte
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf data is not utf-8; you can't "decode" it as utf-8, **because it isn't**.

If you need to send it over a transport that only supports text: base-64 is your best bet. But if you can send it as binary, that would be more efficient.